# Add button outside of Photoswipe Lightbox to open first image with Alpine JS

Tags: php, alpine.js, photoswipe, swiper.js

I have a [Photoswipe Lightbox](https://photoswipe.com/) applied to a [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com/) gallery, and I would like to add a button *outside* the lightbox-wrapper, that opens the first image, no matter what the current visible image is.

Here's the code that populates the gallery and applies the lightbox:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper lightbox">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $gallery as $image_id ): 
    $i++?>
    
        <?php $img_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');?>
        <a <?php if($i == 1) { echo 'x-ref="firstSlide"'; } ?> href="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, $size ); ?>"
            class="relative w-full h-full hover:cursor-pointer aspect-vertical swiper-slide"
            data-pswp-width="<?= $img_info[1]; ?>"
            data-pswp-height="<?= $img_info[2]; ?>"
            target="_blank">
            <?= wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size_medium, false, array('class' => 'object-cover w-full h-full ' . $rounded_elements)); ?>
        </a>
        
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

And here's the button that I'd like to trigger the opening of the first image:

```
<button class="absolute z-50 bottom-12 right-12 flex items-center justify-center opacity-80 hover:opacity-100 transition w-10 h-10 bg-white <?= $rounded_buttons; ?> shadow-md md:w-14 md:h-14 text-primary-dark">
    <i class="icon-resize-full-alt"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [this Github-issue](https://github.com/arnowelzel/lightbox-photoswipe/issues/66) and adapted for AlpineJS.

This can be solved by using `x-ref` and `x-on:click` (or `@click`).

Start by adding an empty x-data to the gallery wrapper:

```
<div class="w-full h-[50vh] lg:h-[450px] 2xl:h-[650px] swiper swiper-gallery" x-data="{}">
```

We can now target the wrapper with Alpine and do whatever we want with it.
After this, add an `$i = 0;` just before the `foreach`.
Just after your `foreach`, you add `$i++` so the $i-variable gets updated for each loop.
Now, on your `a`-element, you add an `x-ref` by checking if the `$i` is 1.

```
<a <?php if($i == 1) { echo 'x-ref="firstSlide"'; } ?> href="[..]" [..]>
```

This will add `x-ref=firstSlide` to, well, the first slide.

After that, we can adapt the button to target that specific `x-ref` by adding the following: `@click="$refs.firstSlide.click()"`

This will click on the element with the x-ref `firstSlide`.

Here's the complete code:

```
<div class="w-full h-[50vh] lg:h-[450px] 2xl:h-[650px] swiper swiper-gallery" x-data="{}">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper lightbox">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $gallery as $image_id ): 
        $i++?>
        
            <?php $img_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');?>
            <a <?php if($i == 1) { echo 'x-ref="firstSlide"'; } ?> href="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, $size ); ?>"
                class="relative w-full h-full hover:cursor-pointer aspect-vertical swiper-slide"
                data-pswp-width="<?= $img_info[1]; ?>"
                data-pswp-height="<?= $img_info[2]; ?>"
                target="_blank">
                <?= wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size_medium, false, array('class' => 'object-cover w-full h-full ' . $rounded_elements)); ?>
            </a>
            
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <button class="absolute z-50 bottom-12 right-12 flex items-center justify-center opacity-80 hover:opacity-100 transition w-10 h-10 bg-white <?= $rounded_buttons; ?> shadow-md md:w-14 md:h-14 text-primary-dark" @click="$refs.firstSlide.click()">
        <i class="icon-resize-full-alt"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```